# Can my lawyer charge fees after termination?

Tags: lawyer, fees

I have asked my lawyer to withdraw from my case and stop communications to and from opposing counsel due to a clear lack of communication on my lawyers end.

She has since sent her notice of withdrawal and my notice of appearance with the court however opposing counsel continues to send communications to my lawyer as she is technically still representing me.

my question is, can my lawyer legally charge me for “reading” communication between counsel before she is recognized as withdrawn from representation even though I have asked her stop communication with opposing counsel and withdraw?

Comment: What is your jurisdiction? Different areas have different laws.

Answer (score 2):

> can my lawyer legally charge me for “reading” communication between counsel before she is recognized as withdrawn from representation even though I have asked her stop communication with opposing counsel and withdraw?

No, except where withdrawal itself requires court authorization. See this [example of a rule](https://www.rib.uscourts.gov/newhome/rulesinfo/html5/Content/9000/9010-1.htm) (specifically 9010-1(e)(4)) where *leave of court* is required for withdrawal. It is unclear from your description whether that is the case.

Generally speaking, your termination of the attorney-client relationship revokes her authorization to read communications that you intend the opposing counsel to send to you (or to replacement counsel, if any). Consequently, she is not allowed to charge you for something she is no longer authorized to do.